# Group by date and count value in nested dict value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the `df1` pandas DataFrame. I would like to transform this DataFrame to have a `count` per each `date` and `concept` (see `df2`).

```
import pandas as pd

inp_data = [
{'date': '2020-02-01', 'concepts': [{'surfaceForm': 'ABC'}, {'surfaceForm': 'DEF'}]},
{'date': '2020-02-01', 'concepts': [{'surfaceForm': 'ABC'}, {'surfaceForm': 'XYZ'}]},
{'date': '2020-02-02', 'concepts': [{'surfaceForm': 'XYZ'}]}
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(inp_data, columns=['date', 'concepts'])

# transform df1 into df2...

# goal
out_data = [
 {'day': '2020-02-01', 'concept': 'ABC', 'count': 2},
 {'day': '2020-02-01', 'concept': 'DEF', 'count': 1},
 {'day': '2020-02-01', 'concept': 'XYZ', 'count': 1},
 {'day': '2020-02-02', 'concept': 'XYZ', 'count': 1},
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(out_data, columns=['day', 'concept', 'count'])
```

Note that the `df1` `date` becomes `day` in `df2`; and each object in `concepts` in `df1` is regarded its own `concept` in `df2`.
I could hack it together with iterating over the rows of `df1` which obviously has lots of performance problems and isn't the pandas way. Then I wanted to run it for a magnitude bigger DataFrame which didn't work in a timely manner.

For reference, here's the hacky way:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['concept', 'day']

def concept_occurence(row, columns):
    insert_list = list()
    for c in row['concepts']:
        sf = c['surfaceForm']
        insert_list.append({'concept': sf, 'day': row['date']})
    return pd.DataFrame(insert_list, columns=columns)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    concept_map = concept_occurence(row, columns)
    df2 = df2.append(concept_map, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Your code isn't working for me. Please edit it so we can more easily help you

Comment: fixed - sorry there were two closing brackets missing @JuanC

Comment: What does 'row_date' contain?

Comment: Others have answered how to get from your first DataFrame to your second one, but you should also consider shaping your first DF differently than you do now. People are sharing good solutions, but those solutions would be less complicated if this first DF was built with more solid data modeling principles. 

You have each record of your data represent multiple objects, so the transformation between your DFs needs to account for that. If you restructure the data before making it into a DF, with each record having a single date and concept, you can make the transformation cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) and `groupby` after [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
a = df1.explode('concepts')
out = (a.assign(concepts = a['concepts'].str.get('surfaceForm'))
       .groupby(['date','concepts'])['concepts'].count().reset_index(name='Count'))
print(out)
```

---

```
         date concepts  Count
0  2020-02-01      ABC      2
1  2020-02-01      DEF      1
2  2020-02-01      XYZ      1
3  2020-02-02      XYZ      1
```

Comment: awesome as always, forgot about `str.get` rarely use it these days

Comment: @Datanovice Thank you :) me too , it was luck that I remembered it :P

Comment: after testing both answers, this version has been considerably faster

Comment: @dh762 yes as it doesn't use apply, anky_91 is a genius

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, we can use explode and pd.series

```
(
    df1.explode("concepts")
    .set_index("date")["concepts"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .reset_index(0)
    .groupby(["date","surfaceForm"])
    .agg(count=("surfaceForm", "count"))
)
```

---

```
                        count
date       surfaceForm       
2020-02-01 ABC              2
           DEF              1
           XYZ              1
2020-02-02 XYZ              1
```

Comment: Very un-novice from your part to post this answer

Comment: @JuanC agreed  'Datapro' +1

Comment: @JuanC haha thanks, when I first joined I was a total newb mainly looking at excel and google sheets stuff. Might upgrade to DataSquire at 10k (:

Comment: That's nice! Didn't know about the `apply(pd.Series)` use case and I also keep forgetting about `explode` so I decided to save your answer for later uses